# UIScrollView change scroll position every visit of the view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

i have a UIViewController with a UIView, and in the view i have a UIScrollView, i initialized the UIViewController in this way:

```
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

when i enter in the View, the UIScrollView it's scroll at Top, if i return back in the MasterView, and then i go again in the DetailView, the view is scrolled at certain position, if i go back, and then i return in the view again, the view is scrolled at another position in the bottom, and again again again, every time i enter, the UIScrollView scroll a little in the bottom every time, so my question is why?...how i can set to top every time i enter in the view?

i have tried this:

```
[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.myScrollView.frame.size.width, self.myScrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

in the viewWillAppear method but don't change anything, so i have put it in the viewDidAppear method, and i see it return up at the top when i enter, so my question is how i can set the uiscrollview to display always at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) animated:NO];`

Comment: with that line in the viewwillappear, work in this way: first time i enter is at top as always, go back re-enter and it's a little scrolled a the bottom, go back re-enter and it's at the top, and repeat this loop, so is a step forward, first instead scrolled more at the bottom and more and more...but it's not perfect...other idea? :(

Comment: I guess depending on how much it scrolls down, you may want to try `CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)`

Comment: Did check that viewWillAppear does indeed get called?